# When i type flutter doctor i get some errors

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I get an error when I type `flutter doctor` to the console.

[image]

These articles keep repeating themselves. What should I do?

Comment: give a try to open cmd as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have made a mistake while installing the flutter sdk. You can try to reinstall flutter SDK, this time you can try to install flutter in a user accessible file and not in system files.

Information about installing Flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Comment: I actually had Flutter installed. Afterwards I got a few errors and tried a few commands. I've been encountering this error ever since. I will upload again. Thanks.